# Matrix factoring

Tags: linear-algebra

In Strang's *Linear Algebra with Applications*, 1988 edition, on p. 308, while proving Schur's lemma, he factors a matrix into two.

The matrix to be factored is a $4 \times 4$ matrix, the first column of which is a normalized eigenvector multiplied by an eigenvalue $\lambda$, the other 3 columns orthonormal vectors to each other (done by the Gram–Schmidt process).

He factors this into a $4 \times 4$ unitary matrix times another $4 \times 4$ matrix the first column of which $a_{11} = \lambda$ and $a_{21} = a_{31} = a_{41} = 0$.  The other 3 columns are unspecified.

My questions are:

1. How does he do this?
2. What do the other 3 columns of the second matrix look like?

Comment: Are you interested merely in knowing one way to do this, or are you anxious to find all possible ways to do this?

Comment: Hardmath -- just one way.  The other 3 columns of the second matrix are important as they undergo further factoring after an eigenvector is found

Comment: The following may make the original question clearer

Comment: I think we need to introduce some additional terminology, and preferably in conjunction with [mathematical notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).  E.g. let's call the matrix you want to factor something like $M$, and let's clear up what the first column eigenvector $v$ is an eigenvector *of*, e.g. $Mv = \lambda v$ ??  I don't have a copy of Strang's *Linear Algebra* handy.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Factoring one matrix into two](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4440814/factoring-one-matrix-into-two)