# Factoring one matrix into two

Tags: linear-algebra

I hope I don't get dinged for asking the same question. The following may make my original question slightly more clear.

On p.308 of Linear Algebra with Applications by Strang (1988 edition), there is a 4x4 matrix named A which has a (normalized) eigenvector named x1 with eigenvalue lambda1

A 4x4 matrix is then constructed by putting eigenvector x1 in the first column  and completing it by Gram Schmidt to form a Unitary 4 x 4 matrix named U1

A then multiplies U1 to give another 4x4 matrix  A*U1.

A*U1 is then factored into two other matrices.  The leftmost is U1. The rightmost is another 4x4 matrix called LAMBDA,  the first column of which is  a11 = lambda1, a21 = a31 = a41 = 0, the other 12 positions filled by *

So we have A * U1  = U1 * LAMBDA

My questions are
l. How do you do this factoring
2. What do the 3 other columns of LAMBDA look like  — you have to know the actual values for the next step
I

Comment: @lewis robinson: You can edit questions you've already asked (there's a little "edit" link at the bottom).  We prefer doing that to creating an entirely new post.

Answer (score 0):

Since the columns of $U_1$ are orthonormal, and $U_1$ is square, it follows that $U_1$ is invertible with $U_1^{-1} = U_1^T$.

This implies that $\Lambda = U_1^{-1}AU_1 = U_1^{T}AU_1$. You can use this to find the columns of $\Lambda$.

To see that the first column of $\Lambda$ is exactly $\lambda_1 e_1$ note that

$U_1^{-1}AU_1 = U_1^{-1}[Ax_1|Au_2| .. |Au_n] = U_1^{-1}[\lambda_1 x_1|Au_2| .. |Au_n] = [U_1^{T} \lambda_1 x_1|U_1^{T}Au_2| .. |U_1^{T}Au_n] = [\lambda_1 e_1|U_1^{T}Au_2| .. |U_1^{T}Au_n]$

by orthonormality of $U_1$. Note that this result holds for arbitrary $n \in \mathbb{N}$.